# How to create a line break within a string being passed to a component in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am currently working on a group project involving a website and one of my group members created a ContentBlock component to help easily make new pages (component below). I have been trying to work on a new page for the site and I am trying to pass a string with newline characters to the component but they are not working properly.

```
export const ContentBlock = ({ title, content }: { title: string,  content: string }) => {
  
return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', paddingTop: '20px', paddingRight: '10px'}}>
      
      {/* Block Header */}
      <h2 style={{
        borderBottom: '4px solid #A1DAFD',
        borderTop: '4px solid #A1DAFD',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: '10px ', color: '#4434A6', fontSize: '40px', fontFamily: 'Sanchez', fontWeight: 'bold' }}> {title} </h2>
    
      {/* Block Content */}
      <p style= {{color: '#4434A6', fontSize: '24px', fontFamily: 'League Spartan', paddingTop: '15px'}}> {content} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried using the newline character within the string being passed to the component as well as trying the 
 tag but both just cause the characters themselves to be displayed, not create new lines.

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                    <ContentBlock title="Sample Title" 
                        content="Sample Content 1\n
                        Sample Content 2\n
                        Sample Content 3\n
                        Sample Content 4"></ContentBlock>
                    <ContentBlock title="Second Content Block" content="Example"></ContentBlock>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "ContentBlock" component we can use "white-space" and set it to "pre-line" which is a CSS property, for paragraph element.

```
export const ContentBlock = ({ title, content }: { title: string,  content: string }) => {
  
return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', paddingTop: '20px', paddingRight: '10px'}}>
      
      {/* Block Header */}
      <h2 style={{
        borderBottom: '4px solid #A1DAFD',
        borderTop: '4px solid #A1DAFD',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: '10px ', color: '#4434A6', fontSize: '40px', fontFamily: 'Sanchez', fontWeight: 'bold' }}> {title} </h2>
    
      {/* Block Content */}
      <p style= {{
      color: '#4434A6',
      fontSize: '24px', 
      fontFamily: 'League Spartan',
      paddingTop: '15px',
      white-space:    'pre-line' // Renderz newline character as line breaks
      }}> {content} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It definitely helps to render newline character as line breaks.
It definitely helps to render newline character as line breaks.